# what is the difference between throwing a new exception within a body of a method and throwing the exception in the header of the method

Tags: java, exception, throw, throws

Hi I wanted to know what the difference and similarities between the two variations of the kind of the same methods would be.

```
public string test(String value)
throw new testException();
```

and

```
public abstract String test(String value) throw new testException;
```

please forgive me if my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public abstract String test(String value) throw new testException;
```

does not make sense.  The closest thing you can do is write

```
public abstract String test(String value) throws testException;
```

which indicates that `test` is a method that *could* throw a `testException`.  If `testException` is not a `RuntimeException`, then it *must* be declared like that.  But adding `throws testException` to the method signature only says that the method *could* throw that exception, it doesn't actually do the throwing.

Comment: perfect thank you, that makes a lot of sense now, I think because it was abstract is what threw met off. @Louis

Comment: @user5647516 You should accept Louis' answer then

Comment: @GregHilston I can in another 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

In java each method should indicate if they are throwing exceptions or not by using this syntax:

```
public String test(String value) throws testException
{
   //your code here
   //at some point you will throw the exception like this:
   throw new testException();
}
```

if you are using abstract method, the method signature only needs to contain the `throws` expression but when you implement the method you need to add the throw statement in the body of the method.